# What changes to make in the code in order to calculate bearings of lines in a shapefile

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I want to calculate bearing of lines in my ArcMap. I have a file in shapefile format. I have found some Python code from [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/34364). This code is use to calculate bearing and azimuth. this is the code:

```
"""
Add fields of azimuths and bearings to a featurelayer of lines.
Azimuths can be based on map or geodgraphic coordinates.
For segmented lines, azimuths are length-weighted averages of segments. """
# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, math, random, traceback, tempfile

# Create the Geoprocessor object
#gp = win32com.client.Dispatch("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

### Check out any necessary licenses
##gp.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
##
gp.OverwriteOutput = 1

# Load required toolboxes...
#gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")

# Script arguments...
try:
    #Get bearing type
    geodesic = 'true' 
#gp.GetParameterAsText(1) == 'true'
     out_feat_class = r'Database Connections\GISADMIN@SDE_Spatial@Smithy.sde\SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.Uploading_New_Data\SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.Airport_ORC_Bearing_Lines'  

    #gp.AddMessage(gp.describe(out_feat_class).shapetype)
    if gp.describe(out_feat_class).shapetype != "Polyline":
        raise Exception,'not a polyline-type feature class'
    #Check for Azimuth field
    fieldnames = []
    fields = gp.ListFields(out_feat_class)
    field = fields.next()
    while field:
        fieldnames.append(field.name)
        field = fields.next()
    if 'SDMBearing' not in fieldnames:
        gp.addfield_management(out_feat_class,'SDMBearing','long',5)
    if 'SDMAzimuth' not in fieldnames:
        gp.addfield_management(out_feat_class,'SDMAzimuth','long',5)

    #Open attribute table for update featureclass
    outrows = gp.updatecursor(out_feat_class)

#Define the bearing, azimuth algorithm
    def geodesic_azimuth(inshape):
        """ Map azimuth calculation from a polyline shape """  
        sumazmlen = 0
        sumbrglen = 0
        sumlen = 0
        line = inshape.getpart(0)
        pnt = line.next()
        if pnt:
            pnt0 = pnt
            pnt = line.next()
            while pnt:
                delx = pnt.X-pnt0.X
                dely = pnt.Y-pnt0.Y
                sdmazimuth = int(89.5-math.atan2(dely,delx)*180/math.pi)
                if sdmazimuth < -90:
                    sdmbearing = sdmazimuth + 180
                elif sdmazimuth > 90:
                    sdmbearing = sdmazimuth - 180
                else:
                    sdmbearing = sdmazimuth
                #gp.AddMessage(str((sdmbearing,sdmazimuth)))
#                sumbrglen += sdmbearing*len
#                sumazmlen += sdmazimuth*len
#                sumlen += len
                pnt0 = pnt
                pnt = line.next()
#        return [sumbrglen/sumlen,sumazmlen/sumlen]
            return [sdmbearing,sdmazimuth]


#Process the lines
    outrow = outrows.next()
    while outrow:
        if geodesic:
            outshape = outrow.shape
            [sdmbearing,sdmazimuth] = geodesic_azimuth(outshape)
            #gp.AddMessage('!: %s,%s'%(sdmbearing,sdmazimuth))
            outrow.sdmbearing = sdmbearing
            outrow.sdmazimuth = sdmazimuth
        else:
            pass #map_azimuth(inrow.shape)
        outrows.updaterow(outrow)
        outrow = outrows.next()
        #georow = georows.next()
except (Exception):
    # get the traceback object
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    # tbinfo contains the line number that the code failed on and the code from that line
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    # concatenate information together concerning the error into a message string
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
        str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
    # generate a message string for any geoprocessing tool errors
    msgs = "GP ERRORS:\n" + gp.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
    gp.AddError(msgs)

    # return gp messages for use with a script tool
    gp.AddError(pymsg)

    # print messages for use in Python/PythonWin
    print pymsg
    print msgs
    raise
```

My question is can any explain me this line in the code:

```
 out_feat_class = r'Database Connections\GISADMIN@SDE_Spatial@Smithy.sde\SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.Uploading_New_Data\SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.Airport_ORC_Bearing_Lines'
```

in order to use it in my case what changes do I have to do over there?

Can anyone check is this working for them in ArcMap 10.5?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please don't paste long complete code in your question - rather focus just on a snippet of code you need help with and tell us about where you are stuck.  Potential answerers are unlikely to run some random code just to see if it works.  Instead tell us what isn't working for you and focus on that for your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
out_feat_class = r'Database Connections\GISADMIN@SDE_Spatial@Smithy.sde\SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.Uploading_New_Data\SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.Airport_ORC_Bearing_Lines'
```

This line is a connection to an [Enterprise Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/types-of-geodatabases.htm#GUID-3566B58A-5BA3-48BF-91C3-5659948BD619).

`Database Connections\GISADMIN@SDE_Spatial@Smithy.sde` Is the ArcCatalog database connection file to the Enterprise GDB

`SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.Uploading_New_Data` is a [feature dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/feature-datasets/an-overview-of-working-with-feature-datasets.htm) in the above Enterprise GDB

`SDE_SPATIAL.GISADMIN.Airport_ORC_Bearing_Lines` is a [feature class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/feature-class-basics.htm) within that feature dataset.

In order for you to use it you'll need to replace that line with reference to your own database and feature class.